# ren *.xml *.xsig works in cmd but not in .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a very simple batch file, I want it to change the extension of all the .xml into .xsig files in the folder of the batch file.
The only line that is in the batch file is:

```
ren *.xml *.xsig
```

The command works fine in cmd, but not by double clicking the batch file, it always reports the next message:

```
The system could not find the file specified
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tested this in windows 7.

Comment: I forgot to say that of course I've tryed the batch in a folder with .xml files in it.

Comment: How did you "try the batch in a folder with .xml files in it" ? what is the exact content of the batch file? How do you know that the batch file was executed on the desired directory? If you add the two lines `echo %cd%` and `pause` you will see the directory that batch is attempting to process.

Comment: The exact content of the batch file is:
`ren *.xml *.xsig
pause`
What it reports is:
`C:\test>ren *.xml *.xsig`
`System couldn't find the specified file`
`C:\test>pause`
`Press any key to continue`
The file is in C:\test folder, so the comand is running in the wright folder

Answer (score 1):

"by double clicking" you start your batchfile with a working folder of `%windir\system32`. I'm quite sure, there are no `.xml` files. Spend your batchfile a `cd %~dp0` to change the working folder to the same where your batchfile resides, or `cd /d` or `pushd` to the proper folder.

Comment: That happens if you run it as admin, I've tried to add `cd %~dp0` at the first line the problem still persist anyway. With that first line it changes to the folder where the batch file is, but it is like the batch is taking the * from *.xml and *.xsig as a literal asterisk.